# User does not have permission to RESTORE database

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

I am using the below code to backup a Database on my local SqlExpress database.

```
  procedure RestoreScoreDb(DBName,OldName,BackName : String);
    var
    cmd : WideString;
    SqlBackupDir : String;
    SqlDataDir : String;
    begin
    Try
    ConnectionMaster.Connected := False;
    ConnectionMaster.Close;
    ConnectionMaster.ConnectionString := 'Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated      Security="";Persist Security Info=False;User ID=SA;Password=Tccc1234;OLE DB Services=-2;Initial Catalog="master";Data Source=\SQLEXPRESS;Initial File Name="";Packet Size=4096;Auto Translate=True;Server SPN=""';
    SqlBackupDir := ReadIniStr(IniCfg,'Dir','SqlBackup');
    SqlDataDir := ReadIniStr(IniCfg,'Dir','SqlData');
    cmd := 'RESTORE DATABASE '+DBName;
    cmd := Cmd + ' FROM DISK = N'''+SqlBackupDir+'\'+BackName+'''';
    cmd := Cmd + ' WITH FILE = 1';
    cmd := cmd + ' , MOVE N'''+OldName+''' TO N'''+SqlDataDir+'\'+DBName+'.mdf''';
    cmd := cmd + ' , MOVE N'''+OldName+'_log'' TO N'''+SqlDataDir+'\'+DBName+'.ldf''';
    cmd := cmd + ' , NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10';
    CmdRestore.CommandText := cmd;
    CmdRestore.Connection := ConnectionMaster;
    CmdRestore.Execute;
    except
    on E: Exception do
    writeln(LogFile,'RestoreScoreDb = '+E.Message);
    end;
  end;
```

The Restore command is

```
cmd ='RESTORE DATABASE score_import FROM DISK = 
N''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\score_import.bak'' 
WITH FILE = 1 , MOVE N''score_import'' TO 
N''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\score_import.mdf'' , 
MOVE N''score_import_log'' TO N''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\score_import.ldf'' , 
NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10'
```

When I copy and paste into management studio it restore the table without trouble. but when I run this code I get an Error:

> User does not have permission to RESTORE database "score_import"

SA has full permission. Any idea what I am missing? Delphi XE6, Windows 10 Sql 2012.

Comment: Unsure if it'll help, but change your Integrated Security = "" to Integrated      Security=False

Comment: Thanks @RachellAmber I just tried this and got "Operation generated error Check each OLE status value, if available. No word was done.

Comment: You might try the code I posted here: stackoverflow.com/questions/43059879/… and see if you get the same problem, If your Delphi version does not have FireDAC, it ought to be possible to do similar with a TAdoQuery, or even a TAdoConnection by itself, but it lloks from your q like you already may be using Ado.

Comment: I have been experimenting and learned something I did not think mattered this code is part of a service designed to replace this database.
If I drop a ADOConection and a ADOCommand on the form and copy the connection string and command string the restore works so there seems to be no problem in the string and more a problem with the fact it is in a service. but this will not work in a service.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Embarcadero support. They could reproduce my problem and resolved it by removing `Integrated Security=""` from the connection string. If you are interested in why, do a Google search for "ADO Integrated Security".